# CakePHP4 / CakeDC keeps asking to login

Tags: php, cakephp, cakedc, cakephp-4.x

I'm using CakePHP 4.0.4 and the latest CakeDC plugin.

My configuration:

**Application.php**

```
class Application extends BaseApplication
{
    public function bootstrap(): void
    {
        ... standard CakePHP code ...
       $this->addPlugin(\CakeDC\Users\Plugin::class);
    }
```

**AppController.php**

```
class AppController extends Controller
{
    public function initialize(): void
    {
        parent::initialize();
        $this->loadComponent('RequestHandler');
        $this->loadComponent('Flash');
    }
}
```

**EventsController.php**

```
class EventsController extends AppController
{
    public function beforeFilter(\Cake\Event\EventInterface $event)
    {
        parent::beforeFilter($event);
        $this->Authentication->allowUnauthenticated(['index']);
    }
    public function index($type='') 
    {
```

When going to the events page, it keeps redirecting me to the login page. What am I not seeing here?

[EDIT]
I've noticed that the `beforeFilter()` of EventsController isn't called.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cakedc.users => always redirect to homepage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39595025/cakedc-users-always-redirect-to-homepage)

Comment: Yes it does, thank you very much.

Comment: Great! I have posted it as an answer

Comment: Im sorry, it did resolve the problem of the page redirecting me to the login page. However, now all pages as public accessible. So this is not the solution.